# Is there a way to focus on a corresponding Chrome tab from DETACHED dev tools window with a shortcut key?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have my Developer Tools configured to open as a detached window. With a simple F12 I open it and it goes on my second monitor without obscuring the browser. Lovely.

I tinker in the DOM, check out the CSS, play in console, often go to another window or browser, do some research and my original browser tab (the one from which I opened the DevTools) gets "burried".

I would very much like to be able to focus on corresponding chrome window and tab by pressing some shortcut key (F12 would be awesome) from the DevTools.

Is that somehow possible? Plugin? Config?

Comment: Hi, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960802/how-to-focus-the-corresponding-tab-of-an-un-docked-chrome-debug-window, it's not a perfect solution, but I think it's a good workaround. It uses element focusing to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try filing a feature request for this in the [Chromium issue tracker](https://crbug.com/new) against the Developer Tools. It currently isn't possible.

EDIT: Oh and <kbd>F12</kbd> isn't possible since that closes the DevTools window. We'd need to find another shortcut.

Comment: Filed. Thanks for suggestion.