# How to focus the corresponding tab of an un-docked Chrome debug window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I often have a lot of tabs open in Chrome browser(s) when developing. I always use the Chrome DevTools un-docked, in a separate window.

Lets say I have opened DevTools for a given tab, then did some search on SO in another tab...
Then if I focus the Chrome DevTools window again, how can I easily find the corresponding browser tab that belongs to this debug window?

I do have a solution, but it is not that straight forward:

- in DevTools, go to tab 'Elements'
- right-click any element inside the  tag
- select 'focus' (at the bottom of the list)

This will bring the corresponding browser to the front and will focus the corresponding tab and will focus the selected element.
This is OK but too many steps and forces to leave the current panel in DevTools (need to go to the Elements tab)

I would like a simple shortcut that just focuses the corresponding tab in the browser.

Comment: I think your solution is good, better than none.. Or do you have a better solution now?

Comment: No better solution for the moment, unfortunately